# vscode extensions need to re-install when I connect next time

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote-ssh

When I use vscode `Remote-SSH`, I install some extensions in SSH server.
But when I connect ssh several days later, the extensions have disappeared which means I have to install again.

- vscode-extensions like these:

  - Python
  - Pylance

Comment: Does it happen for all extensions? Are there any other than Python and Pylance? Or do you have other extensions that this doesn't happen for? Possibly related: [VS Code does not recognize file extensions. Can't install any extensions](/q/75447496/11107541)

Comment: did you had a VSC update

Comment: Any further info in your output logs (`View > Output`)? Are any of these related? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/114046, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1443, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168524, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/7961

Comment: 1. no VSC update. 2. only parts of extensions happened (not local extensions).  I have decided to write `"remote.SSH.defaultExtensions"` config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, if you installed the extension on the SSH host, it'll not remove your extension.

You can open your USER `settings.json` and add the following codes:

```
  "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": [
    "ms-python.python",
    "ms-python.vscode-pylance"
  ]
```

In this way, when you use SSH remote connection, the extension will always remain installed. Read [document for more information about Managing extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_managing-extensions).